# Adding buttons to a few select TinyMCE in WordPress backend by editor id or by WordPress template

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I would like to have a few TinyMCE editor with custom buttons on the backend of Wordpress by using either the editors id's or by applying the customs buttons to all the editors in a select template. I have done this on non Wordpress sites and I have applied buttons to all the TinyMCE editors in the function.php of a Wordpress site but not sure how to just isolate just one editor or just one template. As of right now I think by editor id work would best for me but an example of both ways would be awasome. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks